# How do Interfaces promote code reusablity?

Tags: asp.net, .net, oop, interface

A simple interview question.
How do interfaces help with code reusablity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface decouples the consumer from the implementation details of a class.  This helps enables reusability because the class implementing an interface can change, without needing to change the code consuming the implementation.

That's very confusing, maybe an example helps

```
public interface IUserAuthentication
{
   public bool Authenticate(string name, string password);
}
```

Now I will write the consumer, it doesn't care how authentication is performed, it simply knows that it can authenticate users.

```
public class Consumer
{
  private IUserAutentication _auth;
  public Consumer(IUserAuthentication auth) 
  {
   _auth = auth; 
  }

  public void Working(string username, string password) 
  {
    if (!_auth.Authenticate(username, password)) 
    {
       throw new Exception("error!");
    }
  }
}
```

The code above will work regardless of the implementation of the IUserAuthentication service.  This is one way to reuse code.

Now I can implement the IUserAuthentication interface

```
public class AuthenticateJasons : IUserAuthentication
{
  public bool Authenticate(string username, string password) 
  {
    return username == "Jason";
  }
}

public class AuthenticateNoone: IUserAuthentication
{
  public bool Authenticate(string username, string password) 
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The point is that these implementations are irrelevant as far as the consumer is concerned.  Also, this question is not related to ASP.NET the web framework.  This is really a language/platform/framework agnostic question.  The answer is the same regardless of the language you choose to implement with.

Answer (score 2):

`interface`s allows you to separate the implementation from the information the calling class cares about. This enables you to de-couple your classes from having *intimate* knowledge of classes it depends on.

Given the following `interface`:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
   void Save(T entity);
   void Update(T entity);
   void Delete(T entity);
}
```

A dependent class can be programmed against said interface and be "shielded" from the details.

```
public class SomeService {
    private IRepository<Contact> _contactRepo;

    public SomeService(IRepository<Contact> contactRepo){
        _contactRepo = contactRepo;
    }
}
```

Utilizing this pattern enables you to create different implementations of said interface:

```
public class LinqToSqlRepository<Contact> : IRepository<Contact>
{ /* ... */ }
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<Contact> : IRepository<Contact>
{ /* ... */ }
public class NHibernateRepository<Contact> : IRepository<Contact>
{ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the Open and Close Principle, one of the important law of S.O.L.I.D Principles.

its idea is easy to change with minimum changes in the existing code. And ultimately helps with unit testing.

http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html